# Best way to change several HTML-table cells via javascript

Tags: javascript, html-table

In a HTML-table I have to change several column-headlines, for example: `<th class="myclass">Headline_01</th>` should become `<th class="myclass">Nice Headline 01</th>`. As a beginner in javascript I could achieve this with this code:

```
window.onload = function() {
    'use strict';
    document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace("Headline_01","Nice Headline 01");
    document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace("Headline_02","Nice Headline 02");
    document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace("Headline_03","Nice Headline 03");
}
```

That is what I have:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="myClass1">Current unique Headline for myClass1</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="myClass2">Current unique Headline for myClass2</th>
    </tr>
   ....
  </thead>
```

and that is what I need:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="myClass1">New unique Headline for myClass1</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="myClass2">New unique Headline for myClass2</th>
    </tr>
    .....
  </thead>
```

I have to change 20+ items, and always repeating the same code seems wrong for me and I assume that also leads to bad performance. How should I improve my code? Thanks for hints!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By class

```js
const changes = { 
  "myClass1": "New unique Headline for myClass1", 
  "myClass2": "New unique Headline for myClass2" 
};

Object.keys(changes)
  .forEach(key => document.querySelectorAll("table th."+key)
    .forEach(th => th.textContent = changes[key]));
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="myClass1">Current unique Headline for myClass1</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="myClass2">Current unique Headline for myClass2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
```

By content:

```js
const changes = {
  "Current unique Headline for myClass1": "New unique Headline for myClass1",
  "Current unique Headline for myClass3": "New unique Headline for myClass3"
};

[...document.querySelectorAll("th")]
.forEach(th => {
  const text = changes[th.textContent];
  if (text) th.textContent = text;
});
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="myClass1">Current unique Headline for myClass1</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="myClass2">Current unique Headline for myClass2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="myClass3">Current unique Headline for myClass3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
```

Comment: thank you. Each of my table-heads has their own class and different names that I have to change

Comment: I improved my question to make clearer what I want to achieve.

Comment: Nice, works great, is it also possible to identify a th not by its css-class but by the current content for example: "Current unique Headline for myClass1"?

Comment: Great, I already learned a lot, playing with the solution I realize, that with solution "By class" that names in th that are not addressed via javascript stay unchanged, in solution "By content" all names that are not addressed will be deleted. Is it possible leave the unadressed names unchanged?

Comment: [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Comment: [Rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters)